# "For loop" doesn't iterate through the files

Tags: loops, for-loop, nltk, tokenize

In my simple for loop below, I iterated over 3600 texts, tokenized them and saved them into a list:

```
import glob
import nltk


list = []

for file in glob.glob('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\fake\\*.txt'):
text = open(file,'r',encoding='utf-8').read()
tokenize = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
list.append(tokenize)
```

However, when I try to print out the 10 most common words of these tokens using another for loop as the one below,

```
for tokens in list:
freq = nltk.FreqDist(tokens)
most_common = freq.most_common(10)
```

I end up with a message stating that it has found the following 10 most common words:

```
[('``', 25), ("''", 23), ('que', 18), ('.', 16), ('você', 14), ('ou', 14), ('o', 12), ('e', 11), ('de', 10), ('a', 10)]
```

which is obviously wrong, since 3600 texts have been tokenized. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You collect document tokens into a list of lists, `list` (`list.append(tokenize)`), and then in a `for tokens in list:` loop you assign the `most_common()` value to the `most_common` variable thus getting only the most common terms for the last document only.

I sugges to `.extend` the list of tokens to collect all tokens into a single *flat* list of words, and then getting the top 10 most common tokens by passing the list to the `nltk.FreqDist()` method:

```py
l = []
for text in texts:
    tokenize = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    l.extend(tokenize)
freq = nltk.FreqDist(l)
most_common = freq.most_common(10)
```

Please note that `list` is a Python built-in, do not name variables like that. I chose `l` in the code above.

Comment: Wiktor, you've solved many of my problems!! Thank you very much indeed! Regarding the name of the variable, thanks for the tip, I'll surely use abreviations for Python's built-ins!